# capturing incoming messages in facebook chat

Tags: c#, http, tcp, winpcap, facebook-chat

I wrote a c# program which finds facebook messages in a pcap file. But now its not working.

My program looks for

```
"application/json" and "\"msg\":{\"text\""
```

strings in ipv4 packets.

But yesterday i noticed no such packets are sending anymore. Instead of these now i can distinguish facebook chat packets by searching for

```
"/ajax/chat/send.php"
```

But this string is only for outgoing messages. For incoming messages i couldnt find any key strings. 
Any idea?

Comment: I found the solution myself. Facebook sends chat packets in text/plain http packets with gzipped. So if you want to capture and parse all the facebook chat messages you have to reconstruct tcp session and unzip the stream and parse the string.

Answer (score 1):

Application data (HTTP chat data) in ipv4 packets can be fragmented, i.e. single ipv4 packet may not contain full string "application/json" or "\"msg\":{\"text\"".

Better approach would be to capture higher level HTTP traffic (preparsed by pcap). Here's related information about HTTP traffic sniffing - https://serverfault.com/questions/84750/monitoring-http-traffic-using-tcpdump

Having HTTP traffic dump you can parse messages in more consistent fashion and be sure that fragmentation is not an issue